# Remove all occurrences in a text file with batch script

Tags: batch-file, find-occurrences

Let say in a text file, I have:

> **Planets.txt**
>
> > Mars
> >     Earth
> >     Jupiter
> >     Saturn
> >     Mars
> >     Uranus
> >     Jupiter
> >     Pluto

How can I remove all the occurrences and left the words appear once in a text file?

> **Output_Planets.txt** *(Occurrences: Mars, Jupiter)*
>
> > Mars
> >     Earth
> >     Jupiter
> >     Saturn
> >     Uranus
> >     Pluto

I have no idea how to do that... Thanks.

Comment: [`for` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) might help. Combine `for /F` against `Planets.txt` file contents  with `for %G in (Mars, Jupiter) do @echo %G` (note that `@echo` is here a sample placeholder). Read [ask] and How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: establish a zero-byte output file
SET "newfile=u:\newfile.txt"
COPY /y nul "%newfile%" 2>NUL >nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q33645665.txt) DO (
 FINDSTR /x /i /l /c:"%%a" "%newfile%" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 >>"%newfile%" ECHO %%a
)

TYPE "%newfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q33645665.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces u:\newfile.txt

`FINDSTR` will set `errorlevel` to `0` if a string matching `%%a` is found in the new file. `/x`forces the match to be on the entire line, `/i` specifies that the match be case-insensitive. `/l` makes the match literal, not a *regular expression* and `/c:` preceding a string specifies that the string provided is one element, not a set of strings so that a string containing separators liek spaces can be matched.